# Aligning the edges of two different polygons

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, algebra

I have two different polygons. I want to align the edges of the first polygon with the second polygon edge if the distance between the edge of the first and the edge of the second polygon is less than the threshold value specified.
Only parallel edges must be considered.

So currently how I am doing is
[image: Image link for what i intend to do]

1. I loop through the first polygon and second polygon edges and find the edges of the first polygon and the edges of the second polygon which are parallel to each other.
2. If their distance is less than the threshold value specified, I move the edge points of the first polygon by the corresponding distance value.

Currently, it is working for simple polygons. But for complex polygons when I follow the above approach it results in a self-intersection polygon.

So is there any better algorithm to align the edges of one polygon with respect to another ?

Comment: This question is not suitable for stackoverflow. You can ask it in other communities.

Comment: It is not clear how complex might be you polygons. For convex ones you can try to consider some modification of `separation axes method`

Answer (score 0):

As @MBo says, much depends on whether your polygons are convex (no dents) or not.
If you have arbitrary nonconvex polygons, then the problem is difficult and needs
decisions as to what is desired as the ideal "answer."

If you have P1 and P2 both convex, it seems feasible to calculate the agreement
between edges, identifying the two edges e1 and e2 that are closest. There are various segment-segment measures; perhaps the Hausdorff distance is the most
appropriate.

Then once identifying e1 and e2, you could reposition P2 so that e2 matches e1.